# Qt 5.7.0 with visual studio 2013 add on: Msc_ver 1900 does not match 1800 in moc_test.obj

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5

When I attempt to compile a skeleton project I get a version error: Msc_ver: 1900 does not match 1800 in moc_test.obj . I'm running qt 5.7.0 with add on 1.2.5 in visual studio 2013.  I have checked the platform tools entry in project properties is 2013.

Incase it makes a difference, I do have vs 2015 installed as well.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26822667/1559401) entry?

Answer (score 0):

try using -spec win32-msvc2013 in your qmake command instead of -tp vc:

```
qmake CONFIG-=release CONFIG+=debug -spec win32-msvc2013
```

also make sure you dowloaded Qt for Windows MSVC2013 32-bit